# Check if clicks are within a graphic shape (circle)

Tags: python, python-3.x, window, zelle-graphics

I'm using the Graphics Module Reference "graphics.py"

How do you write a function such that if the user clicks within a circle it should return True otherwise it should return False.

I'm not too sure how to even start. I want to test whether a user's clicks are within a shape or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use getMouse(). This pauses for a user click, then returns the position (as a Point) of the mouse in a window. checkMouse() will return the position of the mouse without requiring a click.

for example:

```
win = GraphWin('Example Window', 100, 100)
mousePos = win.getMouse()
```

Now to use that to determine if the user clicked on a circle:

```
def isClicked(circle, mousePos):
    distance = sqrt(((mousePos.x - circle.x) ** 2) + ((mousePos.y - circle.y) ** 2))
    return distance < circle.radius
```

That would be your function.

Example of code that would use the function:

```
from graphics import *
from math import sqrt

def isClicked(circle, mousePos):
    distance = sqrt(((point.x - circle.x) ** 2) + 
                    ((point.y - circle.y) ** 2))
    return distance < circle.radius

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Example Window', 100, 100)
    circle = Circle(Point(50,50), 25)
    circle.setFill('blue')
    circle.draw(win)
    mousePos = win.getMouse()
    if isClicked(circle, mousePos):
        print "You clicked in the circle!"
    else:
        print "You clicked outside the circle!"

main()
```

Comment: is there another way without using the "from math import sort"?

Comment: Are you asking this because you're getting an error while importing from math? Check for typoes. it's s q r t, not s o r t. That stands for "square root". I might just be blanking out but I can't think of a way to calculate if a point is within the circle without using sqrt or sine functions.

Comment: This example code doesn't actually work.  The first error is, "NameError: global name 'point' is not defined" due to a misnamed formal parameter to `isClicked()`.  But fixing that, with current graphics.py  it fails with, "AttributeError: Circle instance has no attribute 'x'" due to trying to get the 'x' of a Circle which it doesn't have but rather has a center which has an 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

> is there another way without using the "from math import sort"?

Taking your request literally, and fixing bugs in Dardar Fishcake's example, we can do it this way:

```
from graphics import *

def isClicked(circle, point):
    center = circle.getCenter()

    distance = ((point.getX() - center.getX()) ** 2 + (point.getY() - center.getY()) ** 2) ** 0.5

    return distance < circle.radius

def main():
    win = GraphWin('Example', 100, 100)

    circle = Circle(Point(50, 50), 25)
    circle.setFill('blue')
    circle.draw(win)

    while True:
        mousePos = win.getMouse()

        if isClicked(circle, mousePos):
            print("You clicked in the circle!")
            break
        else:
            print("You clicked outside the circle!")

    win.close()

main()
```

Here we substituted `x ** 0.5` for `sqrt(x)`.  Also a slight change in example logic -- this one will keep accepting clicks until you click in the circle.